# Connection to MYSQL with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, hosting

This is my connection class for C#, but it doesn't work:

```
class DB
{
    MySqlConnection connection;
    //Baglanti adında bir bağlantı oluşturdum

    public bool baglanti_kontrol()
    {
        connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=93.89.xx.xx:3306;Database=database_database;Uid=database_userid;Pwd='password';");
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to every solution in the same topic.

My server gives permission for my IP address.

I am getting the following exception:

> 'x.x.x.x' for user 'xx_xx' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'xx_xx'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Is this a server accessed over the Internet? Note that connecting directly to database servers over a relatively high-latency (5ms+) connection is a bad idea because DB protocols are typically very chatty, which amplifies the effects of latency.

Comment: *"...but it doesn't work..."* <- in what way doesn't it work? Please elaborate on any errors you are receiving, what your expected outcome is and what your actual outcome is. Your question in its current state is rather unclear.

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.' @GeoffJames

Comment: @BatuhanAtalay - so, why don't you include this exception in your original question? :)

Comment: @GeoffJames I'm sorry for that. Can help to fix that problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. C# MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql)

Comment: @BatuhanAtalay - as the top answer on the possible duplicate I have posted suggests, it might be that your parameters are not spaced correctly. A useful site I use to ensure I format connection strings correctly is http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: @GeoffJames Now i get 'x.x.x.x' for user 'xx_xx' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'xx_xx'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)'

Comment: @BatuhanAtalay - Long shot - but your `password` in the sample code you have provided is in quotes. Is this a typo in your example, or are you using quotes in the actual code? This might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem
like this

```
"Server=93.89.xx.xx;Port=3306;Database=database_database;Uid=database_userid;Pwd=password;"
```

Problem is  I didn't define "Port" and my password like *'password'*