# Unable to connect to any specified mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linux

I can't connect to my sql server, i tried some fixes from stackoverflow and google and it didn't help me. Thanks.

```
  connString = "SERVER ='''myserverip''';PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword";
        try
         {
             conn = new MySqlConnection();
             conn.ConnectionString = connString;
             conn.Open();
             MessageBox.Show("Connection success");

         }
         catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
```

To configure myuser I used this on my linux vps.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'; CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

i tried : [Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. C# MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql) ( i tried to use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, don't specify the port, instead of password in connection string i typed psw);
Disable my pc firewall, disable linux server firewall

Comment: what does the exception message say?

Comment: @Dale_dale12  " Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching on google how to setup sql connection in linux, and trying different setups hardly I fixed it so I want to share with stackoverflow how I fixed it. Thanks for help [@Avo Nappo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8597963/avo-nappo).

First you need to comment out the line #bind-address from your sql config.
The accepted answer here :[MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts) .

Then I create a user using this command `CREATE USER 'golden'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'golden'@'%';`
And in c# I used my default connection string that is in the question. I don't know why but MySqlConnectionStringBuilder dose not work on my pc. I hope this will help someone. Have a nice day and keep coding.

Answer (score 0):

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder *does* enable you to specify port. Just tested, this works just fine:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.Server = "192.168.1.105";
csb.Port = 3307;
csb.Database = "test";
csb.UserID = "me";
csb.Password = "mypassword";

cn = new MySqlConnection(csb.ToString());
cn.Open();
```

Are you quite sure your MySql server actually accepts incoming connections over TCP? By default that is disabled.

Comment: same error, Unable to connect... maybe is something wrong with how i create the user?

Comment: Well, first suspect then, that the MySql server doen't allow incoming TCP connections. I recall you had to explicitly enable that. See another SO post on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: You are granting access to the user on localhost only. Hypothesis: that server is not on the same machine as the one you are trying to connect from?

Comment: i used CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';` part Specifically, you limit the network access to myuser to localhost. That user will not be able to connect from another computer. Try this instead: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'192.168.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: tied that, dose not work same error, i tried create a new user with @'192.168.%.%' and same error, and when i paste that command i get " Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec) "

Comment: Are you able to connect to that server at all, from another machine? With some sql server management tool a'la HeidiSQL or something?

Comment: tried a windows 10 data link " .udl ", and i get error  https://i.gyazo.com/c06b01d42c33e51c7c3a1265b94f7b2c.png ,HeidiSQL  also don't work

Comment: The Port works fine in linux, i scanned with nmap, and 3306/tcp is open for mysql (no firewall)

Comment: Well, then its most likely MySql server/user access configuration, somehow. In any case, using MySqlConnectionStringBuilder or its equivalent for other server flavours, is generally better than writing connection strings manually. Too easy to get something wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You must go in your **Remote MySQL in your C-Pannel** and Add Access Host first and change this code

```
connString = "SERVER ='''myserverip''';PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword";
```

**to**

```
connString = "SERVER =*Put here your Hostname with Port*;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword;";
```

**Or use this Method**

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder ConStD = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

ConStD.Server = "Hostname that get from Manage Access Hosts";
ConStD.Port = Port that get from Manage Access Hosts;
ConStD.Database = "YourDatabaseName";
ConStD.UserID = "yourUsername";
ConStD.Password = "yourpassword";

try
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConStD.ToString());
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("connection Success");
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**It's Must working For You**

Answer (score 0):

1-Un check all Firewall and Network protection settings
2-Go in database management system running icon like wamp green icon
3-Go to Mysql CMD
3a-

```
CREATE USER 'muzamil'@'%' identified by 'muzamil';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'muzamil'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

These three commands run one by one
4-Windows Defender Firewall
then Click on Advance settings
==> Inbound Rules
->Enable riles Remote Desktop TCP All Rules

5:
C:\wamp64\alias
open this File then
change local to
==> Require all granted
==> Allow from all

Your remote server
will work with c# application