# unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host cpanel

Tags: c#, mysql, cpanel

i get the error

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

```
string conn_string = "Server=jelletaal.nl;Port=3306;Database=jelletaa_thepuckcup;Uid=jelletaa_jelle;Pwd = nP_9+hC_!_2E;";
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connstring = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("succesfully created connection to database");
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

in my cpannel I have created a database called **jelletaa_thepuckcup**

I have created a user called j**elletaa_jelle**

with the password **nP_9+hC_!_2E**

the domain is **jelletaal.nl**

i have also granted my ip adress acces to the database

if anyone knows what i have to do tho get this working, please tell me.

Comment: Not really a good idea to post your username and password on a public site. I hope for you that they are fakes.

Comment: the username and password are fake

Comment: See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql

Comment: the same code works for a local database

Comment: however i want to use a hosted database